# How to match a string array with a string variable?

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-comparison

I have an string array

```
$list = @("abc-1.0.1-xyz", "abc-1.0.2-xyz", "abc-1.0.3-xyz", "abc-1.0.4-xyz")
```

and a variable declared as `$v = '1.0.2'`.

Now I want to compare my array with the variable and get all the strings containing value greater than `$v` in another array.

For example: in this case `abc-1.0.3-xyz` and `abc-1.0.4-xyz` (greater than `$v` i.e. `1.0.2`) will be added to another array.

Answer (score 4):

I would use simple regex:

```
$list = 'abc-1.0.1-xyz', 'abc-1.0.2-xyz', 'abc-1.0.3-xyz', 'abc-1.0.4-xyz'
$v = '1.0.2'
$list | % {
    $match = [regex]::Match($_, '\d+\.\d+\.\d+').Value
    if ($match -gt $v) { $_ }
}
```

**Result**

```
abc-1.0.3-xyz
abc-1.0.4-xyz
```

If you wish to use version comparison (string rules differs, i.e. 10<9), replace condition with following:

```
if ([version]$match -gt [version]$v) { $_ }
```

Comment: Thank a ton. This worked. However, it is including abc-1.0.2-xyz in my new array for some reason. But i will trim it off.. No worries about it :)

Comment: Replace last line with `if ($match -gt $v) { $match }`